# How to fetch the child node with given criteria in javascript DOM api?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xpath

the xml file is like this:

```
<products>
  <product>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>pen</name>
  </product>
  <product>
   <id>2</id>
   <name>pencil</name>
  </product>
</products>
<employees>
  <employee>
   <name>Jack</name>
  <employee>
  <employee>
   <name>Mark</name>
  <employee>
</employees>
```

Can I only get the `<name>` nodes which are the childen of `<product>`? Is there well adapted  `xpath` api in javascript dom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern browsers you could use `querySelector` to traverse the xml-tree. Let's say your xml resides within `div#xmlsample`, then this code will give you a nodeList for `//product/name` in `prodNames`:

```
var xmlDoc = (new DOMParser())
              .parseFromString(document.querySelector('#xmlsample').innerHTML,
              "application/xml"),
    prodNames = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('product name');
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pn3YR/)

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery has an api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) for parsing and traversing xml.

```
var xmlObj = $.parseXML(xmlObj);

var nameNodes = xmlObj.find('product > name');
```

---

From the doc..

> jQuery.parseXML uses the native parsing function of the browser to
>   create a valid XML Document. This document can then be passed to
>   jQuery to create a typical jQuery object that can be traversed and
>   manipulated.

Comment: That's cool! But is there any javascript native implement about this

Comment: Well you asked for an *adapted* API. For some native implementation, see [this article](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I only get the `<name>` nodes which are the childen of `<product>`?

The provided XML isn't a well-formed XML document (a single top element is required).

Also, two `<employee>` start tags don't have corresponding closing `</employee>` end-tags.

**If the correct XML document is this**:

```
<company>
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>pen</name>
        </product>
        <product>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>pencil</name>
        </product>
    </products>
    <employees>
        <employee>
            <name>Jack</name>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <name>Mark</name>
        </employee>
    </employees>
</company>
```

**and an XPath expression is really required**, then one XPath expression that selects the wanted elements is:

```
/*/products/product/name
```

This selects any `name` element that is a child of any `product` element that is a child of any `products` element that is a child of the top element of the XML document.

Comment: +1 for really good formatted answer, I'm using nokogiri in ruby for xpath purpose, is there any native xpath support for javascript, and well adapted ?

Comment: @yozloy, If you search for "Javascript XPath support" you'll find several good links, like this one: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/17/xpath-in-javascript-part-1/